# Как удалить обьект при помощи DI Unity,когда он не нужен?

Tags: c#, di, unity-container

Есть класс unitofWork с одним конструктором

```
 public UnitOfWork(DbContext context) 
        {
            _context = context;
        }
 public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }


        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    _context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            _disposed = true;
        }

        ~UnitOfWork()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
```

в UnityConfig.cs есть следующий код

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, MyContext>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
```

При помощи каких средств можно сделать,что бы после того как я вышел из 
этого конструктора вызвался dispose для unitOfWork каждого UnitOfWork(Так как он должны быть разными) ?

```
 public HomeController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork,IUnitOfWork u)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
            u2 = u;
            var a = unitOfWork == u;
        }
```

Comment: `using(unitOfWork)using(u){....}` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Так это буду делать я,а не DI ,в это там вся и проблема,что дожен произойти вызов dispose() автоматически

Comment: С чего бы вдруг? откуда DI может знать, нужен вам объект или нет? Максимум на что можно расчитывать - то, что GC вызовет этот метод и то, только если у класса есть правильно написанный финализатор, и то не известно, когда он это сделает. Но вообще, раз вы захватываете какой то ресурс в своем классе, то и освобождайте его в своем классе.

Comment: [implement the Basic Dispose Pattern on types containing instances of disposable types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern)

Comment: @tym32167 я реализовал,его но все таки проблема осталось

Comment: @tym32167 HierarchicalLifetimeManager вызывает dispose,но он создает одимн unitOfWork,если я их передаю несколько в конструктор,а я хочу,чтобы были у всех разные ссылки и у всех после вызывались dispose

Comment: `HierarchicalLifetimeManager` - управляет временем жизни в родительских\дочерних контейнерах, он не имеет отношения к захватам ресурсов. Если вам нужны разные объекты, то вам надо `TransientLifetimeManager`, но он тоже не в курсе когда вы освободите ресурсы

Comment: @tym32167 так вот,можно ли как-то задать это время жизни(вот допустим столько же сколько и dbContext)?

Comment: DbContext тоже помирает либо явным вызовом Dispose либо через финализатор. Вам зачем вообще такое надо? Какую задачу решаете? Не надо ничего изобретать, пользуйтесь using или оставьте объекты для GC - но явно вызвать using имхо лучше